# Tensorflow: different placeholder can result different model performance

Tags: python, tensorflow

I found a problem when running tensorflow on GPU. Say X and X1 are placeholders:

```
X = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, name='X', shape=(None, data_len))
X1 = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, name='X1', shape=(num_gpus, None, data_len))
```

`X` and `X1[0]` contain the same features. But the output performance of feeding `X` or `X1[0]` into same model are different.
Can someone explain this?

What is the standard way to feed data when running on multiple GPUs? Currently, I am using a matrix X1 whose first dim is `num_gpus`. But when I compare single GPU version and multiple GPU version with only one GPU, I found this problem, i.e., the output performance of the two settings are different.